# Kotlin - why do I get a KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: kotlin

Consider the following code:

**Example**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    maybeWriteMessage()
}

fun maybeWriteMessage(message: String? = null) {
    writeMessage(message!!)
}

fun writeMessage(message: String) {
    println("Hello World")
}
```

**Output**

> Exception in thread "main" kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException  at
>   com.series0ne.ApplicationKt.maybeWriteMessage(Application.kt:8)   at
>   com.series0ne.ApplicationKt.maybeWriteMessage$default(Application.kt:7)
>     at com.series0ne.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:4)

This is because I'm passing `message!!` (null, damn it!) to a non-nullable parameter, however the parameter is never accessed.

**Question**

Why does Kotlin forcibly throw `KotlinNullPointerException` even when the null reference isn't accessed?

Comment: You're accessing it by dereferencing it: `!!`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`message: String?` is indicating that `message` may or may not be `null`.

Since your function `maybeWriteMessage` has a default value of `null` for `message` and you are calling `maybeWriteMessage()` without specifying `message` - the default value (`null`) will be used when calling `writeMessage(message!!)`.

As written in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) the `!!`-operator throws an exception when the value is `null`.

One way to trigger `writeMessage` safely would be to use `.let`:

```
fun maybeWriteMessage(message: String? = null) {
    message?.let { 
      writeMessage(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: if `message == null`, the `let` block is not executed?

Comment: @GeoffLangenderfer correct! see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#let for more info

Answer (score 6):

Operator `!!` throws an `KotlinNullPointerException` if `message` is null.

You can read about it here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator

Comment: Starting from Kotlin 1.4, the exception will be `NullPointerException` instead (a different type), see [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/08/kotlin-1-3-50-released/). So if any code catches explicitly `KotlinNullPointerException` -- which is discouraged -- then upgrading to 1.4 will be a **breaking change**.

Answer (score 4):

In the following code:

```
fun maybeWriteMessage(message: String? = null) {
    writeMessage(message!!)
}
```

you're asserting that the nullable parameter `message` is not null by using `!!` (the not-null assertion operator). If `message` is null though, this will throw a null pointer.

TL;DR: Do not use `!!` unless you exactly know what you're doing. There's almost always a better way.

> **The !! Operator**
>
> The third option is for **NPE-lovers**: the **not-null assertion operator**
>   (!!) converts any value to a non-null type and throws an exception if
>   the value is null. We can write b!!, and this will return a non-null
>   value of b (e.g., a String in our example) or throw an NPE if b is
>   null:
>
> `val l = b!!.length`
>
> Thus, *if you want an NPE*, you can have it, but you have to ask for it
>   explicitly, and it does not appear out of the blue.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator):

> **The !! Operator**
>   
> The third option is for NPE-lovers: the not-null
>   assertion operator (`!!`) converts any value to a non-null type and
>   throws an exception if the value is null. We can write `b!!`, and this
>   will return a non-null value of `b` (e.g., a `String` in our example) or
>   throw an NPE if `b` is null:
>
> `val l = b!!.length`
>  Thus, if you want an NPE, you can have it, but you
>   have to ask for it explicitly, and it does not appear out of the blue.

So regardless of whether your function uses the parameter or not, by using `message!!`, you are explicitly asking for a NPE.