# How to store multiple images in one document(Firestore) Android

Tags: android, image, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

User should be able to upload multiple images in one post.
I tried to add all urls to a ArrayList and then to store them to firestore.
All I get are errors.

"imageList" returns always null

Here is my code:

```
fun uploadPost(images:ArrayList<Uri>, imageCount: Int, description:String){

    images.forEach { image->
        val imageRef = storageReferenence.child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
                +"."+ image.lastPathSegment)
        val uploadTask = imageRef.putFile((image))
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener {
            val downloadUrl = imageRef.downloadUrl
            downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {uri->
                Log.d("IMAGES", uri.toString())
                imageList!!.add(uri.toString())

                count++
            }
        }

    }



    //firebaseRepository.firestoreDB.collection("post").document(firebaseRepository.userid.toString()).update(post)
}
```

[image]

You can see that the Log has the url but when I try to add it to the imageList
it fails to do so.

THIS CAUSES THE ERROR: imageList!!.add(uri.toString())
ERROR MSG: AddViewModel$uploadPost$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1$1.onSuccess

I don`t really know what is better to store the images as an array or to store each image like this: image1:url... , image2: url..
I need them to be part of the same document.

Comment: At which particular line of code does the error occur?

Comment: imageList!!.add(uri.toString()) ERROR: AddViewModel$uploadPost$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1$1.onSuccess

Comment: Any code that needs the download URL needs to be inside the `onSuccessListener` callback. By the time you now try to use write `imageList ` to Firestore, the `imageList!!.add(uri.toString())` line hasn't run yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699565/how-to-get-download-url-for-firebase-storage-and-update-firestore-document/62699990#62699990

Comment: Log.d("IMAGES", uri.toString())  i get a url here but when I retrieve from the imageList nothing happens it returns null

Comment: I see a kotlinnullpointerexcception. Maybe this link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716294/kotlin-why-do-i-get-a-kotlinnullpointerexception

Comment: @Frank: Good pointer for the client. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Do you have a loop? I see count ++ in the code you provided and I do not see the context.